# Tricky measure subset problem

Tags: measure-theory

[image]

Hi, I am unable to solve the first part, I have tried  many things such as creating an infinite sequence of sets yet cannot seem to prove that they tend to infinity

Answer (score 2):

Let the RHS of expression be $A'$. This case is trivial $\mu(A)< \infty$.  If $\mu(A)=\infty$. Suppose $A'$ is finite. Prove the following:

> 1. Exists $B_n \subseteq A \in \mathcal{A}$ such that $\mu(B_n) \rightarrow A'$.
> 2. Modifying 1. Exists $B'\subseteq A \in \mathcal{A}$ such that $\mu(B') = A'$.
> 3. Then $\mu(A \setminus B') =?$ Does this yield a contradiction?